# Spring boot application not starting in local alone, but same code working in production and development region

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I tried a lot but could not understand what is really wrong
**highlights**

1. Same code starting in development region and production without any issue
2. While starting in local machine am getting the following error

Basically am getting **found [bigint (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [int (Types#INTEGER)]** in my error message, if I change the table field to Integer it is working fine. But the code base is really big and lot of tables involved.

Ideally, it should have started without any error messages.Kindly help me in for this

Note: Same code is was also starting in my older machines, now I got an new machine to work and along with this I got this issue also

Java jre version 1.8.0

Error

```
{"time":"2020-08-19T15:56:23.132+00:00","msg":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext","level":"WARN","app":"food-data-extract-service"}
{"time":"2020-08-19T15:56:23.137+00:00","msg":"Stopping service Tomcat","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","level":"INFO","app":"food-data-extract-service"}
{"time":"2020-08-19T15:56:23.147+00:00","msg":"Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"WARN","app":"food-data-extract-service"}
{"time":"2020-08-19T15:56:23.156+00:00","msg":"Application startup failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)\r\n\tat com.organisation.microservice.extract.Application.main(Application.java:18)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)\r\nCaused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)\r\n\t... 21 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id] in table [cloud_parameter_file]; found [bigint (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [int (Types#INTEGER)]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)\r\n\t... 27 common frames omitted\r\n","app":"food-data-extract-service"}
```

Comment: Could you please also add the entity mapping and database column definition? Also could it be a possibility that in your old setup you were using hbm.ddl on update or create?

Comment: Hi am unable to share the code sorry about it as they are not open sourced. Also what is the hbm.ddl ?
The problem is same code working from another machine no changes done
but in my machine it shows these error

Comment: Sorry i wrote it in short, i meant with "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" property. Also are you using local database setup to connect or dev database on which app is already running fine? other machine also using same database?

Comment: Looks like the DB you are using has the wrong tables. Make sure your db is the same (structure and types) as the one used by others.

Comment: The dB is again in cloud. This is an enterprise all of us are sharing same db and same code. And am the only guy to face to this